# CPanel is warning about inconsistent RPMs for an old MySQL installation -- how do I fix this?

Tags: linux, centos, cpanel, whm

I used the CPanel WHM interface to move MySQL from v5.0 to 5.6 earlier this week. Last night I got an email from my system that claims there are now problems with older MySQL RPMs. The email said:

```
Problems were detected with cPanel-provided files which are RPM
controlled. If you did not make these changes intentionally, you can
correct them by running:

> /usr/local/cpanel/scripts/check_cpanel_rpms --fix

The following RPMs are found to be altered from their original install
state: 
compat-MySQL51-shared,5.1.73,4.cp1136,/usr/lib64/libmysqlclient.so.16.0.0
```

And when I ran check_cpanel_rpms on the machine I got:

> /usr/local/cpanel/scripts/check_cpanel_rpms --list-only
>   prelink: /usr/lib64/libmysqlclient.so.16.0.0: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
>   [20141025.184811]
>   [20141025.184811]   Problems were detected with cPanel-provided files which are RPM controlled.
>   [20141025.184811]   If you did not make these changes intentionally, you can correct them by running:
>   [20141025.184811]
>   [20141025.184811]   > /usr/local/cpanel/scripts/check_cpanel_rpms --fix
>   [20141025.184811]
>   [20141025.184811]   The following files were found to be altered from their original RPM:
>   [20141025.184811]   compat-MySQL51-shared,5.1.73,4.cp1136
>   [20141025.184811]

That's 5.1 it's complaining about which is not the currently running version.

The `--fix` option on `check_cpanel_rpms` is pretty magic -- I'm not certain it's safe to run; it's likely it'll take down my MySQL instance as part of the "fix".

How do I correct this warning? I'd prefer a method that wouldn't have me incur a MySQL outage if that's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to run that command, you can try running EasyApache to rebuild Apache/PHP with correct mysql client extension, although that was already run probably, if you choose the unattended upgrade, as some of your sites wouldn't work after the MySQL upgrade if it wasn't done.

Also, I don't think you will have any issues if you run

`/usr/local/cpanel/scripts/check_cpanel_rpms --fix`.

I have run the command multiple times on servers to resolve issues just like this, and have never had issues with it.

If you have made a MySQL upgrade through WHM, the command should just remove old MySQL RPMs and leave the current MySQL 5.6 RPMs in place.

You should backup all your databases before running the command just to be safe, in case anything goes wrong, but it shouldn't cause any MySQL downtime.

You can backup all databases by running

```
mysqldump --all-databases > all_databases.sql
```

to backup all databases in one file, or

```
for i in `mysql -e "show databases;"`; do mysqldump $i > /folder_path/$i.sql; done
```

to backup each database in its own file.

Comment: Yup. I did already run EasyApache to rebuild the extensions. I went with running `check_cpanel_rpms --fix` and it downloaded the `compat-MySQL51-shared-5.1.73-4.cp1136.x86_64.rpm` RPM and installed. No downtime to my 5.6 MySQL instance and the command line `mysql` binary appears to be 5.6 still. No more warnings from `--list-only` output.